# finding large videos in the OSX Photos app

Tags: photos.app

Is there a way to find all videos above a certain size using the new Photos app so that they can be selected for Export or put in an album?

I'd like to move large videos off to an external drive, but I can't find a way to select them (or indeed, to find them at all).

Comment: what is wrong with Finder all files sorted by type

Comment: @Buscar웃SD I only have 41 movies in Finder and 320 in Photos.app, apparently Finder does not show files from Photos.app

Comment: use "All my Files" and it should show them.

Comment: Looking at All My Files, I am baffled about how to make it show videos or, indeed, any large files at all.  It bears no resemblance to what I know is on the disk.

Answer (score 6):

1. Navigate to **Pictures** folder
2. Right click on Photos Librar and **Show Package Contents**
3. Open the **originals** folder (prior to macOS 10.15 / Catalina, the 'originals' folder was named 'Masters')
4. In search bar, type **mov**, then choose Type '**Movie**'
5. Make sure '**Masters**' is still the search target
6. Right click the column headings and tick '**Size**'
7. Click **Size** column header to sort

*Do not change anything in Finder. Just use it to identify the videos, then go back to Photos to make changes.*

Answer (score 5):

This can be done via the free version of [PowerPhotos](https://fatcatsoftware.com/powerphotos/) (`brew cask install powerphotos`)

1. Open your Photos library in PowerPhotos
2. In the menu bar `View` section, select `As List` and `Show Columns → Size`
3. Click the size column to sort by file size
4. You now have a list with where the biggest files are easy to spot

Comment: I can't recommend PowerPhotos more. WELL worth the reasonable price... and really adds features that Photos SHOULD have in the first place.